# org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException Failed to start browser \\?\C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe: other os error

Tags: selenium-firefoxdriver, geckodriver

I am trying to launch firefox browser using following code;

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class test00104 {

    @Test

    public void testerror15() throws InterruptedException{
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","D:\\WorkSpace_Shweta\\UIAutomation\\lib\\geckodriver.exe");
        //System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.bin","C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.google.com");
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("http://www.google.com")).sendKeys("Selenium hq");
    }
}
```

Somehow it doesn't work and the error I get is:

`org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException Failed to start browser \\?\C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe: other os error.`

I saw couple of posts but didn't find an answer.
Environment used: Selenium 3.4.0, Gecko 0.16.0 and FF 53.0.3

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem which was caused by the quota of `/tmp` being exceeded so that geckodriver wasn't able to create a Rust profile directory (`rust_mozprofile*`) there.

You can use the `TEMP` environment variable to specify a different location for those profiles (see https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/299). Also, make sure to properly shut down the driver using `driver.quit()` in order to prevent the profiles from filling up your `TEMP`.